# Use self declared UTI(Uniform Type Identifiers) in iOS extention

Tags: ios, objective-c, extension-methods

I want my share extention only appear when a self declared UTI file shares.
I register a UTI in my containg app like this:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>my uti</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.my.uti</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>com_my_uti</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And i register my extention can support this, which make it can receive PDF and my own UTI file:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
<string>
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
        || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.my.uti"
        ).@count >=1
).@count >=1
</string>
```

However, it can receive PDF but cannot receive my own UTI type file.